# Change datetime format received from google calendar api in spring controller class

Tags: spring-mvc, google-calendar-api

I am using google calendar api to retrieve events and display in my calendar.I am using spring mvc and angularjs.I am able to get all the events from calendar api.But i am getting event start and end date in this format

```
    {"dateTime":"2018-02-23T14:00:00.000-08:00"}
```

But i want to change this into string type in this format for example

```
    2/23/2018 1:30 PM
```

Here is my Controller.java

```
    AddEmployee employee = salesSettingService.getloginuserdetails();
        if(employee.getGoogleAccessToken()!=null) {
            List<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();
            events = salesNotifyService.getEventsFromGoogleCalendar(employee.getGoogleAccessToken());/*Here i am calling another method which returns all events from google*/
            for (Event event : events) {
                System.out.println(""+event.getStart());
                SalesNotify salesNotify = new SalesNotify();
                salesNotify.setEmployeeName(event.getSummary());
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy h:mma ");
                try {
                    Date notifyDate = dateFormat.parse(event.getStart().toString());
                    Date notifyEndDate = dateFormat.parse(event.getEnd().toString());
                    salesNotify.setNotifyDate(notifyDate.toString());
                    salesNotify.setNotifyEndDate(notifyEndDate.toString());
                } 
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                   

                salesNotify.setNotifyType("other");
                allNotifies.add(salesNotify);
              }

        }
```

But if i print in console i am getting null for both notifyDate and notifyEndDate.Can anyone tell how can i change the format of datetime from google?

Comment: Why do you think using a SimpleDateFormat with the pattern "dd/MM/yyyy h:mma " to parse a string looking like ""2018-02-23T14:00:00.000-08:00" makes any sense? The pattern clearly doesn't match the format of your string, does it? Google for "how to parse a date in Java".

Comment: you appear to be confusing _parsing_ a date (i.e. turning a string in a specific format into a Date object) with _displaying_ a date (i.e. turning a Date object into a string in a given format). When you parse the date from Google you should tell the parser to expect the format which google supplies. When you display your date in your view, then you should use the custom format that you're showing here.

Comment: N.B. however if the `getStart()` method in your `Event` class already returns a `DateTime` object, then parsing in this case is entirely unnecessary since you already have the needed object. All you need to do is tell your view to _display_ the date in your desired format